# App Crashes while processing image in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a image processing app. One can have many layers on images and can save them to disk. Here's the code that does that (`TransparentBG.png` is **3000x3000** transparent image):

```
CCSprite *blankImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"assetsFullSize/TransparentBG.png"];
//CCSprite *blankImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"assets/centerPaneBG.png"];
blankImage.tag=SAVE_IMAGE_BASE_TAG + [[AppManager instance] generateNextSaveImageIndex];
NSLog(@"   blankImage.tag = %i",blankImage.tag);
NSLog(@"   blankImage.size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(blankImage.contentSize));
for(int i=1; i<[layers count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"   i = %i",i);

    ImageFeature *feature = [layers objectAtIndex:i];
    CCSprite *layer = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:LAYER_INDEX_BASE + i];
    NSLog(@"   ********* layer.position = %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(layer.position));
    NSLog(@"   ********* feature.posX,posYition = %i,%i",feature.posX,feature.posY);
    //        [layer removeFromParent];
    //        CCSprite *layerCopy = [layer copy];
    CCTexture2D *texture = [layer texture];
    CCSprite *layerCopy = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
    layerCopy.anchorPoint = layer.anchorPoint;
    NSLog(@"   anchorPoint = %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(layer.anchorPoint));
    //        layerCopy.position = ccpAdd(layer.position,ccp(-LEFT_PANE_WIDTH,0));
    //        layerCopy.position = ccp([self getImageFeature_posX_fomSpritePosition:layer],[self getImageFeature_posY_fomSpritePosition:layer]);
    layerCopy.position = ccp((feature.posX/3000) * blankImage.contentSize.width,(feature.posY/3000) * blankImage.contentSize.height);
    layerCopy.position = IS_RETINA ? ccp(feature.posX / 2,feature.posY / 2) : ccp(feature.posX,feature.posY);
    NSLog(@"   ********* layerCopy.position = %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(layerCopy.position));
    layerCopy.color = layer.color;
    layerCopy.scaleX = layer.scaleX / VISUAL_SCALING_FACTOR;
    layerCopy.scaleY = layer.scaleY / VISUAL_SCALING_FACTOR;
    layerCopy.rotation = layer.rotation;
    layerCopy.opacity = layer.opacity;
    [blankImage addChild:layerCopy z:i tag:layer.tag];
    //        layer.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
    //        layer.position = ccpAdd(layer.position,ccp(-LEFT_PANE_WIDTH,0));
    //        [blankImage addChild:layer z:i tag:layer.tag];
}

//    CCSprite *attribution = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"assets/pikpark.png"];

//    CCSprite *attribution = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"assetsFullSize/pikpark.png"];
//    attribution.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
//    attribution.position = ccp(blankImage.contentSize.width-  (attribution.contentSize.width/2.0),attribution.contentSize.height/2.0);
//    attribution.opacity = 64;
//    [blankImage addChild:attribution z:8999 tag:ATTRIBUTION];

//    blankImage.scale = 300.0/blankImage.contentSize.height;
CGPoint p = blankImage.anchorPoint;
[blankImage setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];

//  CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:300 height:300];
//  CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:1500 height:1500];
//  CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:3000 height:3000];
CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:blankImage.contentSize.width height:blankImage.contentSize.height];

[renderer begin];
[blankImage visit];
[renderer end];

[blankImage setAnchorPoint:p];

UIImage *thumbImage = [renderer getUIImage];

NSLog(@"   thumbImage.size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize([thumbImage size]));
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",blankImage.tag];
NSLog(@"   key = %@",key);
CCSprite *renderedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:thumbImage.CGImage key:key];
NSLog(@"   width=%3f   height=%3f",renderedSprite.contentSize.width,renderedSprite.contentSize.height);

// And save to UserDocs
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *galleryDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gallery"];
NSLog(@"   galleryDirectory = %@",galleryDirectory);

NSString *saveFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%i.png",blankImage.tag];
NSLog(@"   saveFileName = %@",saveFileName);

NSString *galleryPath = [galleryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];
NSLog(@"   galleryPath = %@",galleryPath);

NSError *error;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbImage);
[imageData writeToFile:galleryPath options:NULL error:&error];// atomically:NO];
NSLog(@"   GALLERY IMAGE SAVED!");
```

I have tested it on the simulator, and works fine. But when I test it on my iPad2, it crashes giving memory pressure fatal exception.

Through breakpoints i can see that the following line is making the app crash giving the memory pressure exception from the above set of code.

```
UIImage *thumbImage = [renderer getUIImage];
```

If I change the size of the `CCRenderTexture *renderer` to **300x300** the app stop crashing. But it severely screws with the quality and size of the image being saved. **3000x3000** generates superb quality images. I tried using `despatch_async` but got no success with that.

Is there anyway I can work around the `memory pressure` issue? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3000x3000 texture consumes over 34 Megabytes of texture memory.

You create a texture from the image (x1). Then you create a render texture for rendering (x2). Then you create a UIImage from the render texture (x3). Finally you create a NSData with UIImagePNGRepresentation (x4).

So the same texture memory is held in various buffers in memory at this point in time, at least 4 times = 136 MB.

I say "at least" because some texture loading inefficiencies are known in cocos2d and may exist in UIImage etc as well. For example creating a CCTexture2D may actually create two buffers of the same size, so real memory usage could be 170 MB. Run Instruments to find out how much memory is really used.

One thing you can try is to separate the individual parts to allow temporary buffer being freed from memory. For example after loading the CCTexture2D, don't create the sprite and render texture right away but dispatch of performSelectorInBackground:afterDelay: with a delay of maybe a 20th of a second. You can do the same after creating the UIImage from render texture so that the PNG representation is put on hold for another fraction of a second.

Comment: You saved me from a lot of frustrated moments. Thanks! :)